# Additional fields to passport-local-mongoose account registration?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, passport.js, passport-local

I'm using passport-local-mongoose with Node.js, Express.js, MongoDB for a webapp, and I want to register users with a username field, a password field, a company name field, and a phone number field (all as Strings). However I am only able to get the username and salted password to show in the database. How do I also include the company name and the phone number fields in the database?

Comment: "var newUser            = new User();" after that "newUser.firstName = req.body.firstName;" thats all

Comment: Need to define the fields in the schema too

Answer (score 4):

Just pass in the required model fields as an option.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    passportLocalMongoose = require('passport-local-mongoose');

var userSchema = mongoose.Schema;
var User = new userSchema({
    username: ...,
    admin: ...,
    // Configure other schema fields
});

User.plugin(passportLocalMongoose, {
   selectFields : 'username admin etc' //Space seperate the required fields
);
```

And when registering,

```
// user_details contains all information required
// for registration such as username, password, admin, etc.
User.register(new User(user_details), user_password, cb);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it is actually helped me a lot

Comment: I tried your suggestion but it says `user_details ` is not defined!